# python: how do I pull the If else statement into this loop when lambda is involved?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, lambda

I have many functions that sometimes should loop sometimes shouldn't. I want to build in an option to tell it to loop. Here is my code. You can see that every function has the `if... else` statement. Is there a way to put the `if... else` statement into the method `loop`? So I don't have to repeat those lines for every function?

```
import inspect

def test1(b,shouldloop=False):
    if not shouldloop:
        a = b + 1
        print a

    else:
        loop(lambda z: test1(z) , inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

def test2(d,e,shouldloop=False):
    if not shouldloop:
        a = d * e
        print a

    else:
        loop(lambda z: test2(z,e) , inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

def test3(g,h,i,shouldloop=False):
    if not shouldloop:
        a =  g **2 - h + i
        print a

    else:
        loop(lambda z: test3(z,h,i) , inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)

def loop(function,c):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    for i in x:
        function (i)
        print c
```

so sometimes I just need the function `test1` to not loop like so...

```
test1(2)
```

output:

```
3
```

and sometimes I need it to loop like so...

```
test1('',True)
```

output:

```
2
test1
3
test1
4
test1
5
test1
```

The other test functions have more variables. But I will be using them the same way.

Comment: I don't understand your logic flow here, what is this code supposed to output? Also, instead of using `'yes'` for your `shouldloop` you should just use a boolean value

Comment: I agree with @Sayse, that is quite complicated. Can you provide a more clear explanation of your code?

Comment: Since you're doing 6 separate things in the 3 sets of `if... else...` blocks, it's probably best to leave it like this.  I fear any other attemps to pass a set of `if... else...` block that does different things into different functions is just gonna be a hot mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite `loop` as a decorator to add it around arbitrary functions:

```
import functools

def loopable(fnc):  # decorator, takes any function
    @functools.wraps(fnc)
    def fncloop(*args, shouldloop=False, **kwargs):  # take loop switch and arguments for the actual function
        if shouldloop:  # loop logic
            x = [1,2,3,4]
            for i in x:
                fnc(i, *args[1:], **kwargs)  # replace first argument with i
                print(fnc.__name__)
        else:
           fnc(*args, **kwargs)  # call function unconditionally
    return fncloop  # return wrapped function
```

Apply it when defining a function, which just contains the loop body:

```
@loopable
def test1(b):
    a = b + 1
    print(a)
```

Any decorated function now supports `shouldloop`:

```
>>> test1(2)
3
>>> test1(2, shouldloop=True)
2
test1
3
test1
4
test1
5
test1
```

---

For Python 2, you have to fetch the argument from `kwargs` explicitly:

```
import functools

def loopable(fnc):
    @functools.wraps(fnc)
    def fncloop(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('shouldloop', False):
            x = [1,2,3,4]
            for i in x:
                fnc(i, *args[1:], **kwargs)  # replace first argument with i
                print(fnc.__name__)
        else:
           fnc(*args, **kwargs)
    return fncloop
```